# Help with finding a solution to this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, roots

How would one find the solution to the following differential equation? I am asking because I believe there are no roots, and this is puzzling me.

$$  \frac{x^2}{x^2 - x + C} = \frac{dx}{dt}$$

Some rearranging gives:

$$  dt = \left(\frac{C}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x} + 1\right) dx$$

Integrating gives:

$$  t+K = x -\frac{C}{x} - \ln(x) $$

Setting $$  t+K  = G $$

$$  x -\frac{C}{x} - \ln(x) - G = 0 $$

I now want to find the root of this equation, but since $x$ can not equal zero, I don't think one can find a root. So: How would one find a solution to this? Would it just have to be a non-zero solution?

Comment: You're correct that the solution function has no roots. However this doesn't impact the existence of the solution.

Comment: Note that the expression for $t$ in terms of $x$ is not invertible for general values of $C, K$. In any case, there is not a closed-form expression for $x$ in terms of $t$ (even after restricting to an interval on which the formula for $t$ in terms of $x$ is one-to-one).

Comment: $x$ should not be a real or complex value, it should be a function of $t$.

Comment: So how would one express c as a function of t? Can you prove your statement Travis?